# How to sum overlapping data ranges with INDEX(MATCH()) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-analysis

In summary, this formula is checking multiple conditions to determine the appropriate depreciation value based on the year, ISO week number, and specified data ranges. I am getting stuck with my formula, which is almost giving me the desired output. Can anyone help me finding my flaw? The logic is explained below:

1. I have a list of investments and each investment has different depreciation intervals.
2. The objective is to place depreciation on the income statement, in case depreciation intervals overlap they should be added.

This is the source where the lookup data is found:

[image]

A few words for context:

1. The data range called: DATA_DEPRECIATION is created to summarize all depreciation amounts per data interval.
2. The depreciation is displayed per week in the income sheet. On a separate input sheet an investment is added with a start date and end date. The first two columns show year and week number calculated from the date field. This way they can be matched to a week in the income statement.

**Now the question.** Below is a snapshot of the income statement for context:

[image]

1. The first investment starts on 1-sep-2023 and ends 29-sep-2023. The corresponding week codes are 202335 and 202339.
2. The second investment starts 22-sep-2023 and ends 27-oct-2-23. The corresponding week codes are 202338 and 202343.

The expected output is:
Cel B23: $2500,
Cel C23: $2500,
Cel D23: $2500,
Cel E23: $3500 (overlap cell and therefore the found amounts should be added),
Cel F23: $1000,
Cel G23: $1000,
Cel H23: $1000,
Cel I23: $1000,
Cel J23; $0

The actual output can be found in the example. I have used this formula to get to this point:
[image]
[This is a link to the sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16KXL8KjJXynu8SZvXYZKnsG76Dl5VGN1KchALaVRIzI/edit?usp=sharing)
I am getting stuck, yet feel I am close to the desired output. Can anyone help me spot the flaw in my formula?

These are two investments in a long list of investments. The idea is to just add new investments to the list and the formulas place them on the appropriate places on the income statement (and other statements) based on the date criteria.

Thank you to anyone that can help me unstuck!

Comment: I haven't fully researched/understood your whole helper(isoweeknum) setup and all but here's something you can test out and see since its matching with your expected output. for *Cell_E23*: `=sumifs(investments!$L:$L,investments!$F:$F,"<="&E8,investments!$K:$K,">"&E8,investments!$R:$R,"Investment")` [https://i.imgur.com/OdrqiDE.png](https://i.imgur.com/OdrqiDE.png)

Comment: @rockinfreakshow  Thank you very much for this solution. This works. Could you help me turn this into an arrayformula? I'd like to prevent copying cells across the row. Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(B8:8,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumifs(investments!L:L,investments!F:F,"<="&Σ,investments!K:K,">"&Σ,investments!R:R,"Investment"))))
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. It's also above my paygrade ;-). Going to study this, because it seems this will elevate my skills as well. Thank you!

Comment: For all of you like me, who want to learn more about the lambda function in sheets, here is a good article: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-use-the-lambda-function-in-google-sheets-standalone/